# Twitter get request_token problems with async - 401 Error

Tags: c#, twitter, asynchronous

I'm having problems getting a request token back from Twitter asychronously - the server returns "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

Here's the code I'm using -

```
public void AcquireRequestToken(Action<bool> response)
{

    string oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));

    // build the signature
    var headers = new Dictionary<string,string>()
    {
        { "oauth_consumer_key", _oAuthConfig.ConsumerKey },
        { "oauth_nonce", oauth_nonce },
        { "oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1" },
        { "oauth_timestamp", MakeTimestamp() },
        { "oauth_version", "1.0" },
        { "oauth_callback", PercentEncode(_oAuthConfig.Callback) },
    };

    string signature = MakeSignature ("POST", _oAuthConfig.RequestTokenUrl, headers);
    string compositeSigningKey = MakeSigningKey(_oAuthConfig.ConsumerSecret, null);
    string oauth_signature = MakeOAuthSignature(compositeSigningKey, signature);

    Uri fullUri = new Uri(_oAuthConfig.RequestTokenUrl);

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullUri);
    request.Method = "POST";

    request.Headers.Add("oauth_consumer_key", PercentEncode(_oAuthConfig.ConsumerKey));
    request.Headers.Add("oauth_nonce", PercentEncode(oauth_nonce));
    request.Headers.Add("oauth_signature_method", PercentEncode("HMAC-SHA1"));
    request.Headers.Add("oauth_timestamp", PercentEncode(MakeTimestamp()));
    request.Headers.Add("oauth_version", "1.0");
    request.Headers.Add("oauth_callback", PercentEncode(_oAuthConfig.Callback));
    request.Headers.Add("oauth_signature", PercentEncode(oauth_signature));

    try 
    {

        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(result =>
        {
            string contents = String.Empty;
            HttpWebRequest theRequest = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;

            if (theRequest != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpWebResponse theResponse = (HttpWebResponse)theRequest.EndGetResponse(result);

                    using (Stream stream = theResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                    Dictionary<string, object> results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(contents);

                    _requestToken = (string)results ["oauth_token"];
                    _requestTokenSecret = (string)results ["oauth_token_secret"];

                    response(true);
                }
                catch (WebException e)
                {
                    response(false);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                response(false);
            }
        }), request);

    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        response(false);
    }

}
```

My old (non-async) code works fine -

```
public bool AcquireRequestToken()
{
    var headers = new Dictionary<string,string>()
    {
        { "oauth_callback", PercentEncode(_oAuthConfig.Callback) },
        { "oauth_consumer_key", _oAuthConfig.ConsumerKey },
        { "oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1" },
        { "oauth_timestamp", MakeTimestamp() },
        { "oauth_version", "1.0" }
    };

    string signature = MakeSignature ("POST", _oAuthConfig.RequestTokenUrl, headers);
    string compositeSigningKey = MakeSigningKey(_oAuthConfig.ConsumerSecret, null);
    string oauth_signature = MakeOAuthSignature(compositeSigningKey, signature);

    var wc = new WebClient ();
    headers.Add ("oauth_signature", PercentEncode(oauth_signature));
    wc.Headers [HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = HeadersToOAuth(headers);

    try
    {
        var result = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(wc.UploadString (new Uri(_oAuthConfig.RequestTokenUrl), ""));

        if (result ["oauth_callback_confirmed"] != null)
        {
            _requestToken = result ["oauth_token"];
            _requestTokenSecret = result ["oauth_token_secret"];

            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

The headers are slightly different in the new version, but keeping them the same doesn't help.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong with the header. There is only one HTTP header called `Authorization` :

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="<the consumer key of your app>", oauth_nonce="<the nonce>", oauth_signature="<the signature>", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="<the timestamp>", oauth_token="<your token>", oauth_version="1.0"
```

This page will tell you how to make it : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request. It is the same for all the methods except for two methods :

- `request_token` needs `oauth_callback` but not `oauth_token` (normal since you do not have it).
- `access_token` needs `oauth_verifier` (you will get it after the second step).